# How to store additional fields from Google/Facebook using SimpleMembership & mvc4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

The mvc4 internet template have the following code

```
OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
```

Is there any support for persisting other attributes such as country, last/first names etc. or you roll your own using EF/other orm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add additional fields to the membership DB through the existing API. But you can use the `ProviderUserId` to map your own entity to the one in the membership database.